# How to count all rows that have an apostrophe in a table in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot count the rows which have an apostrophe in a table. Here is my query.

```
$name = "'"; // variable declared for apostrophe

$script_select = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS rowcount FROM (SELECT * FROM   my_db.my_tb WHERE (customer_name REGEXP '".$name."' 
OR address_line_1 REGEXP '".$name."'  OR address_line_2 REGEXP '".$name."'
OR address_line_3 REGEXP '".$name."' OR address_line_4 REGEXP '".$name."'
OR address_line_5 REGEXP '".$name."')) counted");

     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($script_select))
     {
         $sel_row = $row['rowcount'];

     }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just run a normal query like this instead of all that regex and subqueries:

```
select
    count(*) as recordCount
from
    my_db.my_tb
where
    customer_name like '%\'%'
    or address_line_1 like '%\'%'
    or address_line_2 like '%\'%'
    or address_line_3 like '%\'%'
    or address_line_4 like '%\'%'
    or address_line_5 like '%\'%'
```

Answer (score 1):

For simple pattern matching, you can use LIKE, but you need to escape the quote character:

```
$script_select = mysql_query(
    "SELECT COUNT(*) AS rowcount FROM my_db.my_tb ".
        "WHERE customer_name LIKE '%''%' OR address_line_1 LIKE '%''%' OR address_line_2 LIKE '%''%' OR address_line_3 LIKE '%''%' OR address_line_4 LIKE '%''%' OR address_line_5 LIKE '%''%'");
```

And you don't need the subquery - a regular `COUNT` will suffice.

P.S. in this case, SQL injection isn't an issue, but you should not use `mysql_*` functions any longer - switch to mysqli or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can replace REGEXP by LIKE and using

```
 $name = "%\'%";
```

It should do the job :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = "%''%"; // variable declared for apostrophe

$script_select = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS rowcount FROM (SELECT * FROM   my_db.my_tb WHERE (customer_name LIKE '".$name."' 
OR address_line_1 LIKE '".$name."'  OR address_line_2 LIKE '".$name."'
OR address_line_3 LIKE '".$name."' OR address_line_4 LIKE '".$name."'
OR address_line_5 LIKE '".$name."')) counted");
```

Comment: Hi All,

Thank you for your help. It is now resolved.